# Get object information that caused the exception

Tags: ruby, exception, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have written the following piece of code to handle my exception.

```
class Business < ExceptionController
  def work(arg1,arg2)
        #####some business logic that cause exception
  end
end

class ExceptionController < ApplicationController
  rescue_from Exception, :with => :render_error_response

  def render_error_response(e)
     p e.message
     p e.backtrace
  end
end
```

I log the message and backtrace in `render_error_response` defined in exception controller. I want to print the arguments of the function i.e., `arg1`, `arg2` of `work` function that caused the exception.

Along with exception backtrace, I need the object information on which def work was called .

Comment: You better first make your code syntactically valid.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to decorate the exception message yourself.

```
class Business < ExceptionController
  def work(arg1, arg2)
    #####some business logic that cause exception
  rescue => ex
    ex.message << (" (arg1: %p, arg2: %p, self: %p)" % [arg1, arg2, self])
    raise ex
  end
end
```